# Make array created with mdadm (raid 5) active again (editing mdadm.conf)

Tags: raid, mdadm, read-only

I'm pretty new to linux but somehow, 6 months ago, I managed to set up my home server with a RAID 5 (2 Tb x 5 disks) and it has been great so far, until yesterday I started having error transferring data via smb share. So i decided to reboot the server but when it restarted, i got the error "a start job is running for dev-md0.device"

Searching online seems like the array can't automatically reassemble itself and can't mount the main directory on it

in fact if i type 'mount -av' it gives me 
'/boot/efi           :already mounted
none                 :ignored
[   260-800762] EXT4-fs (md0): unable to read superblock
mount: /mnt/raid5: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

Nonetheless the array is present since after typing 
'cat /proc/mdstat/
it returns: md0 : inactive sdf1[5] (S) sdc11 sde1[3] (S)' ....  etcetera etcetera...

Searching online I also found this could be my case https://superuser.com/questions/117824/how-to-get-an-inactive-raid-device-working-again

But when I try ">> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf" it won't give me permission since it's a read-only file

I also tried to write mdadm.conf manually with sudo vim but still i won't write and save

I'm sorry if i wasn't clear but i'm really new to this I can't solve this alone

I'm really stressed out because I have a lot of data on that ARRAY and i really want to get it up and running again

Thank you everybody for helping

Comment: please copy paste the full ouput of /proc/mdstat , or at least a picture of the screen

Comment: root@rhcserver:~# /proc/mdstat
bash: /proc/mdstat: Permission denied
--So I tried--
root@rhcserver:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : inactive sdf1[5] (S) sdc1[1] (S) sdd1[2] (S) sde1[3] (S) sda1[0] (S)
          9766907320 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>